# Searching function for linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, search, linked-list

I'm sure this is very simple, but I'm new to linked lists and a bit rusty on pointers. I'm used to coding in C++ where you can easily pass parameters, but in C not so much. So I get confused when things don't work as easily.

I basically just want a function inside my program that receives a passed variable and searches the linked list for it. I have it working in main, but having it as a separate function is giving me headaches.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int globalNum = 1; 

typedef char DATA;
struct node
{
    DATA d;
    int nodeNum;
    struct node *next;
};


main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *tail = NULL;
    int nodeNum;

/*CREATE*/  
    while(globalNum <= 5)
    {
        struct node *new;
        if((new = malloc(sizeof(struct node))) == NULL) abort();

        new->next = NULL;
        new->nodeNum = globalNum;
        globalNum++;
        if(!head) head = new;
        else tail->next = new;
        tail = new;
    }


/*ACCESS*/
    struct node *access;
    access = head;
    while(access)
    {
        if(access->nodeNum != 5)
        {
            printf("%d\n", access->nodeNum);
            access = access->next;
            printf("NEXT\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("FOUND\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if(!access)
        {
            printf("CANNOT ACCESS\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

@555k
Thanks for advice with the double pointers! I've made a similar function for the access code, but it doesn't read the linked list nodes and segmentation faults. How can the search function know what the `access->next` location is? What needs to be passed when calling `search(&head);`?

```
int access(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *access;
        access = head;
    while(access)
        {
            if(access->nodeNum != 5)
            {
                printf("%d\n", access->nodeNum);
                access = access->next;
                printf("NEXT\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("FOUND\n");
        }
    if(!access)
        {
                printf("CANNOT ACCESS\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how did u passed the "struct node" and value "access"

Comment: your main does not have any return type and you are returning 0; if element was found

Comment: `if(!access) ... return 0;` //cannot next step

Comment: Start by working out what paramaters your function needs, and what it must return (for failure as well as success). Then the code is easy.

Comment: No need of passing double pointer in search.Double pointer is required for create because you are modifying the pointer inside the function and it needs to be reflected back in main. but no such modification in search function. Check my code mate

Comment: If you use double pointer itself then modify as access = *head; in your code. It will solve your seg. fault

Comment: @555k - Thanks again, you're a life saver mate. I tried to get it to run without the double pointer. But it said it was expecting a double pointer if I were to call the function with `access(&head);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think double pointer is the answer for your question for creating functions check this...

```
int globalNum = 1; 

typedef char DATA;
struct node
{
    DATA d;
    int nodeNum;
    struct node *next;
};

void Create(struct node **head, struct node **tail)
{
    while(globalNum <= 5)
    {
        struct node *new;
        if((new = malloc(sizeof(struct node))) == NULL) abort();

        new->next = NULL;
        new->nodeNum = globalNum;
        globalNum++;
        printf("\nBEFORE CREATE\nhead = %d\nnew = %d\ntail = %d", *head, new, *tail);
        if(!(*head)) *head = new;
        else (*tail)->next = new;
        *tail = new;
        printf("\nAFTER CREATE\nhead = %d\nnew = %d\ntail = %d\n", *head, new, *tail);
    }
 }
 void Access(struct node **head)
 {    
    struct node *access;
    access = *head;
    while(access)
    {
        if(access->nodeNum != 5)
        {
            printf("%d\n", access->nodeNum);
            access = access->next;
            printf("NEXT\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("FOUND\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if(!access)
        {
            printf("CANNOT ACCESS\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
  }

main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *tail = NULL;
    int nodeNum;

    Create(&head, &tail);

    Access(&head);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou!
But when executing, the code result isn't as expected.
`
135434312
NEXT
27112
NEXT
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
`

Comment: Where is the segmentation fault in Create or in Search function??. Which search function you used(with or without double pointer)???. you checked all my comments??

Comment: Thanks, it's all working now with double pointers. I just had to learn the proper syntax when using pointers in functions and called functions. You've been a great help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
access = access+1;
```

Use

```
access = access->next;
```

EDIT:

```
void search(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *access;
        access = head;
    while(access)
    {
            if(access->nodeNum != 5)
            {
                printf("%d\n", access->nodeNum);
                access = access->next;
                printf("NEXT\n");
             }
             else
             {
                printf("FOUND\n");
                access = access->next;
             }
             if(!access)
             {
                 printf("CANNOT ACCESS\n");
             }
     }
```

}

Calling above function as :

```
search(head);
```

from main should work.

Comment: Woops, sorry. I had the wrong version of code in my clipboard. But I've fixed that now. (Edited original post)

I'm still trying to pass the memory locations, or somehow use pointers to pass the head node to a function. I'm not sure how this would be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the function for you, but I will write the specification:-

```
// Looks for node with a specific nodeNum value in the list passed in.
// Returns a pointer to the node if found, or NULL if the node isn't there.

 struct node * findNode(structnode * listHead, int valueToFind)
{
// your code here
};
```

Usage:

```
  struct node *result;
  result = findNode(head, 5);
  if (result != NULL)
    ...
  else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `NULL' undeclared here (not in a function) when using the library file stdlib.h it even has #define NULL 0